# Calling contract deployed on Tezos sandbox using Taquito

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, tezos-signer

I've a simple contract deployed on Tezos sandbox (https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/2-sandbox/) and I'm using Taquito in frontend to call this contract.
Earlier, I deployed the contract to global testnet and used the key to set provider (using `InMemorySigner`), but what should I give as key if I'm using a sandbox running on my localhost? I tried giving some random key but it gave me server error. (Also, any way to see some kind of logs from the server, ie, deployed sandbox to see what exactly went wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

Flextesa comes with 2 preinstalled accounts: Alice and Bob. You can find their secret key in the link that you provided (the value after `unencrypted:`):

```
- alice
  * edpkvGfYw3LyB1UcCahKQk4rF2tvbMUk8GFiTuMjL75uGXrpvKXhjn
  * tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb
  * unencrypted:edsk3QoqBuvdamxouPhin7swCvkQNgq4jP5KZPbwWNnwdZpSpJiEbq
- bob
  * edpkurPsQ8eUApnLUJ9ZPDvu98E8VNj4KtJa1aZr16Cr5ow5VHKnz4
  * tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6
  * unencrypted:edsk3RFfvaFaxbHx8BMtEW1rKQcPtDML3LXjNqMNLCzC3wLC1bWbAt
```

You can use Alice's or Bob's secret key in the `InMemorySigner` when running contracts in your sandbox.